# How to filter out  using regular expression in C#?

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-2

How to filter out space using regular expression in C#?

Answer (score 1):

You might show some code about HOW you are sorting/displaying that list.

To remove initial numbers from a string:

```
string newString = Regex.Replace(oldString, @"^\d\s*", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `/^\d\s*/` with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all whitespace from a string, use

```
result = Regex.Replace(subject, @"\s+", "");
```